# How to set minimum time in datetime picker in ej2 syncfusion

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, ej2-syncfusion, ej2-angular-calendars

I have a date time picker ej2 syncfusion in which when i select any date time sets too 12:00am how i can set this default auto time to something else value

I tried min value which takes default current date value and time minimum which i want but which leads to not able to select date prior to current date

Comment: `var datetimepicker = new ej.datetimepicker.DatePicker({
    min: new Date(new Date().setHours(9,0,0,0)), // set minimum time to 9:00 AM
    value: new Date() // set the default value to current date and time
});`